# Is it possible to root the Samsung Galaxy Fit?

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-fit

I have a Samsung Galaxy Fit. I am not able to find any guide on the web regarding how to root it. Is there some method suitable for beginners?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to some users in [this thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1056243), application named "[SuperOneClick](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=803682)" is able to successfully root your handset.  You will need to install it on your computer (various Windows and Linux flavors available).